# Very simple for loop error Java

Tags: java, loops, methods, for-loop, arraylist

I have no idea why this isn't working.

```
public static int getMaxPosition(ArrayList<Integer>list)
{
    int max=list.get(0);
    int maxPos=0;
    int curr;
    int c;
    for (c=0; c<list.size(); c++);
    {
        curr=list.get(c);
        if (curr>max);
        {
            maxPos=curr;
            max=curr;
        }
    }

    return maxPos;
}
```

This block of code gives a runtime error (IndexOutOfBoundsException) at the line `curr=list.get(c);`, and I can't find any good reason for it.

Comment: It'd be more idiomatic to go through the list with `for (int curr : list)` instead of messing around with an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a semicolon after your for-loop, and then the block brackets. The semicolon causes the loop to excute, and then it drops into the block. The for-loop increments c to c == list.size(), and then drops into the execution block.

This is the working code:

```
public static int getMaxPosition(ArrayList<Integer>list)
{
    int max=list.get(0);
    int maxPos=0;
    int curr;
    int c;
    for (c=0; c<list.size(); c++)
    {
        curr=list.get(c);
        if (curr>max)
        {
            maxPos=curr;
            max=curr;
        }
    }

    return maxPos;
}
```

Comment: `if (curr>max);` Do You think It's Correct?

Answer (score 4):

You have a semi-colon after your `for` loop. 
So, it will execute till `c < list.size()`, and then it will exit when your `c` becomes `list.size()`. Now, your `list.get(c)` will get executed for that `c = listsize`, which is out of bounds.

```
for (c=0; c<list.size(); c++); <-- //Remove Semi-colon
```

Also, there is a semi-colon after your inner if: -

```
if (curr>max);  <-- // Remove this also.
```

**NOTE: -** It would be more *readable* for others and *easier* for you, if you iterate your `list` using `enhanced for-loop`: -

```
for (int curr: list) {
   if (curr>max) {
       maxPos=curr;
       max=curr;
   }
}
```

Comment: There is another semi-colon after the "if" statement that needs to be removed

Comment: These kinds of error you can easily remove if you pass your code through a `debugger`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (c=0; c<list.size(); c++);
```

if (curr>max);

Remove semi-colon. Semi-colon ends the statement.

Your code should be something like below:

```
for (c=0; c<list.size(); c++)
{
curr=list.get(c);
        if (curr>max)
        {
            maxPos=curr;
            max=curr;
        }
...
```

}